# Using mutating function in std::accumulate

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++03, std

There are cases where

```
x += y;
```

is a lot more efficient than

```
x = x + y;
```

(assuming `x` and `y` are of some class type with complex overloaded operators). Now of course I could do a fold with

```
X x;
BOOST_FOREACH(Y const &y, collection)
    x += y;
```

(I am stuck on platform with old compiler) but I somehow prefer `std::accumulate`. Is it possible to make it (or other algorithm, but not for_each) to use `+=` instead?

The `std::accumulate` is supposed to call the operator like

```
sum = op(sum, *iter);
```

but can one rely on it, that is, will

```
X x(std::accumulate(collection.begin(),
                    collection.end(),
                    X(),
                    std::mem_fun_ref(&X::operator+=)));
```

work?

Comment: What's wrong with `std::for_each`?

Comment: yes you can rely on it. you could do a really ugly hack. don't.

Comment: @Rapptz: It does no longer offer any advantage over the loop, neither in code length nor in amount of abstraction.

Comment: You can't use `std::accumulate`, because that is required to not modify any element in the range, and `+=` pretty clearly will modify an element.

Comment: @BillLynch: not in the *range*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as your guarantees go..

C++03 [lib.accumulate]:

> Requires: T must meet the requirements of CopyConstructible (20.1.3) and Assignable (23.1) types. `binary_op` shall not cause side effects.

So the function must not have any 'side effects'. Which is defined as follows:

C++03 [intro.execution]:

> Accessing an object designated by a volatile lvalue (3.10), **modifying an object**, calling a library I/O function, or calling a function that does any of those operations are all side effects, which are changes in the state of the execution environment.

emphasis mine.

Note that in C++11 the wording changes slightly (§ 26.7.2):

> Requires: T shall meet the requirements of CopyConstructible (Table 21) and CopyAssignable (Table 23) types. In the range [first,last], `binary_op` shall neither modify elements nor invalidate iterators or subranges.

However, you could make a tag type that kind of works with whatever you throw at it and is a null operation..

```
struct tag {
    template<typename T>
    tag& operator=(const T&) { return *this; } // not explicitly necessary
};
```

Then you make a functor that accepts that tag type on its left hand side and a closure to maintain the result.

```
struct accumulator {
    int& x;
    accumulator(int& x): x(x) {}
    tag operator()(tag t, int y) {
        x += y;
        return t;
    }
};
```

then use it as normal..

```
std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), tag(), accumulator(x));
```

and it should work. Though I think at this point `std::for_each` is a better alternative or maybe the `BOOST_FOREACH` macro.

You could also write your own algorithm which would be less boilerplate-y:

```
template<typename It, typename T, typename Op>
T inplace_accumulate(It begin, It end, T init, Op op) {
    for(; begin != end; ++begin) {
        op(init, *begin);
    }
    return init;
}
```

Then you just feed it the regular accumulator with this signature:

```
struct accumulator {
    template<typename T>
    void operator()(T& x, const T& y) const {
        x += y;
    }
};

// somewhere else
int x = inplace_accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 10, accumulator());
```

Comment: At this point the `BOOST_FOREACH` is a better alternative. Not interesting.

Comment: @JanHudec Well yeah. The other alternative would be to write your own algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can rely on it.

You could write your own really *ugly* operator, ignore the sum, and hope that the compiler will optimize the junk you've created.

Please don't. I doubt anybody would like to read that code.

Why don't you roll your own algorithm?

```
template<class InputIt, class T>
T accumulate_fast(InputIt first, InputIt last, T init)
{
    for (; first != last; ++first) {
        init += *first;
    }
    return init;
}
```

This is generic and doesn't need a separate custom binary operator for each type.

Comment: This answer is **inconsistent**. Please, choose. Either I *can* rely on "it" (= op is called `sum = op(sum, *iter)`) in which case I *don't* have to roll out my algorithm as `std::accumulate` with `std::mem_fun_ref(&T::operator+=)` will work, or I should roll my own algorithm in which case the reason is I *can't* rely on "it".

Comment: There's no inconsistency. You can rely on it, it's just that it's an ugly hack. I didn't say you *have to* roll your own algorithm. But in my mind rolling your own results in a clearer code.

Comment: Did you read what "it" is? Apparently not. The hack you mention does **not use "it"**. Relying on "it" would not require that hack.

Comment: @JanHudec: I read it (*again*, just to be sure), thank you very much... and I have no idea what you're talking about. As I said you can rely on it. If you have problem with that, please disprove it. That's the best thing I can do at the moment, because, as I said, I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it clearer what I am talking about. And I have accepted the other answer since relevant standard quote was added (no, I can't rely on it, or at least can't abuse it).

Comment: @JanHudec: sry, I had c+11 in mind. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate - "op must not invalidate any iterators, including the end iterators, or modify any elements of the range involved." - neither of which you need.